# Replacing one unicode character in a string

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I have a problem with an utf-8 encoded XML text. In Notepad++ it looks like this. Besides normal spaces there are some U+2002 ("ENSP") characters.

[An XML-text with a non-visible unicode character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9lgd.png)

How can I get rid of them:

*str.replace*("u'2002'", " ") does nothing.

*str.encode* and *str.decode* are not available, because of the version of Python.

*Regex* and *unicodedata.normalize* loose Scandinavian characters and make the text generally unusable.